# Is it considered bad practice calling a provider directly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, membership, roleprovider

I'm implementing a Custom RoleProvider in the .NET Membership-framework. The existing functionally needs a little tweaking, so I want to implemenet my own Public Functions, to invoke around the static Roles-class.

Instead of Object -> Roles -> RolesProvider
I would go Object -> RolesProvider

Would this be considered bad practice? The only alternative with the current databasescheme is to ommit the use of RoleProvider totally, and implement my own custom system for authorization.

Edit: To clarify, I have already implemented a custom MembershipProvider, so the desire to keep working in the Membership-framework is pretty high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any time you circumvent part of a framework or customize it in a way that was not intended it could be considered bad practice**.  It is the intention of the ASP.NET membership provider framework to facilitate access to the current provider through the `Roles` class.

The danger of 'bending' the framework to suit your needs instead of extending it as intended is this: **there may be other areas in the .net framework, configuration or tools around the role membership functionality that make this assumption, and they may no longer make sense after your changes and cause confusion for others involved in your project**.  The ASP.NET Website Administration Tool is one example of a tool that makes this assumption.  If someone were to use this tool after your changes, your role memberships and site could be potentially corrupted as a result.

If you decide to take this approach you should carefully consider what functionality you are adding and ultimately ask yourself it is really necessary.  If it is, you may be better off implementing something completely custom instead to avoid confusion.